# Symfony 6.2 witch docker php-fpm

Tags: php, symfony, docker-compose, dockerfile, symfony6

i have a problem with my production environnement.

In local i'm using php-cli and in production php-fpm and in production when `$Response->send()` is excecuted, i pass in the first `if(\function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request')))` and this show me a white page instead of my render.

In my PublicController.php i have this :

```
    #[Route('/user/validate/account', name: 'user_validate_account', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function validateEmail(Request $request, SecurityService $securityService): Response
    {
        if($this->getUser() && $this->getUser()->getIsEmailVerified() && !$tokenRequested = $request->get('token')) return $this->redirectToRoute('public_home');

        $securityService->forceLogout();
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->remove('_user_validate_account_security_token');

        if($tokenRequested = $request->get('token')) {
            $securityToken = $this->securityTokenRepository->findOneByToken($tokenRequested);

            if(!$securityToken) {
                $this->addFlash('globalInfo', "Le token de sécurité est invalide !");
                return $this->redirectToRoute('public_user_validate_account');
            } elseif($securityToken->getTokenType() === SecurityToken::_VALIDATION_EMAIL) {
                if ($securityToken->getExpiresAt() < DateUtility::now()) {
                    $this->addFlash('globalInfo', "Votre token de sécurité à expiré, merci renouveler votre demande !");
                    $this->securityTokenRepository->remove($securityToken, true);
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('public_user_validate_account');
                }

                $securityToken->getUser()->setIsEmailVerified(true);
                $this->securityTokenRepository->flush();
                if ($securityToken->getUser()->getIsPasswordNeedToChange()) {
                    $session->set('_user_validate_account_security_token', $securityToken);
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('public_user_validate_password');
                } else {
                    $this->addFlash('globalInfo', "Votre compte est vérifié, bonne gestion :)");
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('public_home');
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('security/user_validate/account.html.twig');
    }
```

In local, with php cli when

```
    $securityService->forceLogout();
```

is executed, script will continue and show my render. But in production i'm using php-fpm and i have a white page.

My `$securityService->forceLogout();` use Response from HttpRequest of Symfony:

```
    <?php


    namespace App\Service;

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\LogoutEvent;
    use Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;

    class SecurityService
    {

        public function __construct(
            private readonly RequestStack             $requestStack,
            private readonly EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher,
            private readonly TokenStorageInterface    $tokenStorage
        )
        {}


        public function forceLogout() : void
        {
            $logoutEvent = new LogoutEvent($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest(), $this->tokenStorage->getToken());
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch($logoutEvent);
            $this->tokenStorage->setToken(null);
            $response = new Response();
            $response->headers->clearCookie('REMEMBERME');
            $response->send();
        }
    }
```

When $response-send(); :

```
    /**
     * Sends HTTP headers and content.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function send(): static
    {
        $this->sendHeaders();
        $this->sendContent();

        if (\function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
            fastcgi_finish_request();
        } elseif (\function_exists('litespeed_finish_request')) {
            litespeed_finish_request();
        } elseif (!\in_array(\PHP_SAPI, ['cli', 'phpdbg'], true)) {
            static::closeOutputBuffers(0, true);
            flush();
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

In production, i go to the 2nd elsif, and this show my page with my render, but in production i enter in the first if (\function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request')) and this show me a white page 200.

Someone can help me to fixe this please ?

Comment: `php-cli`? That's the command line interpreter/shell version of PHP, no web support

Comment: If you're using output buffering you'd need to also do an `ob_flush` and a `flush` before terminating the request

Comment: This is the reason why you would use the same setup locally as in production, otherwise you'll get "it works on my machine", so: replicate what you have in production and then chase your bug. Add error_reporting to your php.ini, you know, the usual stuff